# How to read a new Array data after push values using d3.csv?

Tags: javascript, arrays, csv, d3.js

I have a block of code that `push` objects to a `new Array` from csv file using `d3.csv()`.

I do not understand why `console.log(data[0])` returns `undefined`.

This is my code:

```
let data = []
let csv = 'file.csv'
let read_csv = d3.csv(csv, (d) => {
  d.map((i) => {
    data.push(i)
  })
})
console.log(data)
console.log(data[0])
```

First *console* returns all values as follow: `Array(166)`. However, the second one returns `undefined`.

What am I doing wrong? Is this the proper way to select the array's `index` using this method?

**Edit**

I tried this code also:

```
var read_csv = d3.csv(csv, function (d) {
  for (var i = 0; i < d.length; i++) {
    data.push(d[i])
  }
})
```

If I tried this:

```
let read_csv = d3.csv(csv, (d) => {
  d.map((i) => {
    console.log(i)
  }) 
})
```

It returns each object, so I believe `d3.csv()` is reading data ok.

Comment: What happens when you `console.dir(data)` ? That will show you the underlying data.

Comment: It returns also `Array(166)`.

Comment: But is there a collapsable triangle beside it  that will let you see the underlying array members?

Comment: Make sure you read the [doc](https://github.com/d3/d3-3.x-api-reference/blob/master/CSV.md)

Comment: Did you check your data?

Comment: Yes, there is. @msanford. All data is in there. But I cannot get data by index.

Comment: Yes, @nevabyte. `map` function returns single values. The problem is with the Array.

Comment: Try `data.push(i); console.log(data[0]);`, have you tried using a counter for the array and setting such as `data[counter] = i`?

Comment: can you post you file.csv structure?